# sscan doesn't returns part of members

Tags: redis, set

I have a set which contains **integer** values. And I want to retrieve part of it with [sscan](http://redis.io/commands/sscan).

```
127.0.0.1:6379[1]> smembers d
 1) "1"
 2) "2"
 3) "3"
 4) "4"
 5) "5"
 6) "6"
 7) "7"
 8) "8"
 ...
```

But sscan returns full list of members:

```
127.0.0.1:6379[1]> sscan d 0
1) "0"
2)  1) "1"
    2) "2"
    3) "3"
    4) "4"
    5) "5"
    6) "6"
    7) "7"
    8) "8"
    9) "9"
    ....
```

Is there any way which brings me members page by page(for eg. 10 items for every scan)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `COUNT` directive as explained in [`SCAN`](http://redis.io/commands/scan)'s documentation to return a fixed number of results.

Comment: Values of the member are integer !

Comment: I'm unsure why that is relevant. In any case, note that Redis uses strings to stir numbers in any case.